# Java naming clash between method variable and package names

Tags: java, web-services, axis, convention, name-clash

I have some classes generated from WSDL files by the Axis Framework. In one of these classes, there is a generated method

```
public com.initechsystems.www.initech7.initechbo.Organization createOrganization(com.initechsystems.www.initech7.initechbo.Organization org) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {

//(... snip ...)
_call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
//(... snip ...)
}
```

The variable name org in the method parameter creates a naming clash with package org.apache.axis.client, as the compiler cannot differentiate between the package and variable. I realize I can fix this easily by changing the variable name org in the method, but I would like to avoid this, because it slows down the workflow. Is there some way around this other than either modifying the WSDL file or the generated classes?

**Compiler error:**

```
 D:\projects\java\initechdir\target\generated-sources\axistools\wsdl2java\com\initechsystems\www\initech7\initechws\OrganizationManagement\OrganizationManagementSoapStub.java:[1678,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable apache
location: class com.initechsystems.www.initech7.initechbo.Organization
```

Comment: Please post the text of the compiler error.

Comment: Edited in original post.

Comment: That's funny (as in "ha ha", not as in "weird"). I guess I've never tried to name a variable java or javax or org before.

Comment: yea, I thought the same thing.

Comment: This humor is supplied by some "Initech" developers, who developed the .NET web service, probably without considering the consequences of such a variable name. But I agree, it is funny in some kind of way.

Comment: The compiler mentions symbol apache. Can you post line 1678?

Comment: Line 1678 is _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
as mentioned in the original post. The symbol "apache" confuses the compiler, because apparently it expects it to be a property of the org variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a way to cause that generated code to have import statements?  That would prevent you from having to have the fully-qualified name of the class.

So, if you could add:

```
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
```

to the file then your method call would just be:

```
_call.setProperty(Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
```

I'm not sure if Axis has an option for that though.  If not I'd say renaming the variable (maybe to "organization") would be the best thing.  I would recommend avoiding manual edits of auto-generated files, as that makes regenerating them harder.

Comment: That's a good idea, but I think it's not possible - at least I haven't found a way to do it..